# How to handle NoHttpResponseExcpetion in htmlunit 2.9

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am getting below Exception when i click on submit button of my form. After searching it more on google, looks like this exception is thrown when server didn't response to the request submitted by HTMLUnit. I am using HTMLUnit 2.9.

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.download(WebClient.java:2131)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm.submit(HtmlForm.java:135)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput.doClickAction(HtmlSubmitInput.java:75)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1244)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1195)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1158)
        at com.quinstreet.dms.qaautomationtool.testengine.LeadSubmitter.submitForm(LeadSubmitter.java:1518)
        at com.quinstreet.dms.qaautomationtool.testengine.LeadSubmitter.processFodPage(LeadSubmitter.java:627)
        at com.quinstreet.dms.qaautomationtool.testengine.LeadSubmitter.submitLead(LeadSubmitter.java:431)
        at com.quinstreet.dms.qaautomationtool.testengine.LeadSubmitter.run(LeadSubmitter.java:174)
        at com.quinstreet.dms.qaautomationtool.util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:123)

Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:101)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:252)
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:281)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:247)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:219)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:298)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:776)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:152)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1439)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1358)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.download(WebClient.java:2127)

Please suggest a solution or any kind of clue to fix this issue.

Comment: Does this page work with a normal browser?

Comment: What else have you tried?

Comment: Can you post what URL you're trying to hit and some code that you've tried.

Comment: Yes, it works with normal browser, I tried the solution mentioned here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452910/how-can-i-disable-or-specify-the-number-of-retries-in-htmlunit-java but it didn't work for me.